# Spdep: Test for heteroscedasticity in GMerrosar residuals

Tags: r, testing, spdep

Using `spdep` in **R**, and after conducting a **Jarque-Bera** test confirming non-normality of the residuals resulting from the maximum likelihood estimation of my **Spatial Error Model**, I used the generalized moments technique (`GMerrorsar`). Now I want to test if the residuals from the `GMerrosar` present problems of **heteroscedaticity** in order to decide whether to stay at this step or go to estimate a **SHAC** model.

What test in `spdep` can check heteroscedasticity from an `GMerrorsar` model ?
I see that the **Breusch-Pagan** (`bptest.sarlm`) test is not applicable in this case.